# Using Terraform, how can I orchestrate deploy of many related/dependent stacks?

Tags: terraform

CloudFormation doesn't provide tools for orchestrating deployment of several/many stacks. For example consider a microservice/layered architecture where many stacks need to be deployed together to replicate an environment. With cloudformation you need to use a tool like stacker or something home grown to solve the problem.

Does Terraform offer a multi-stack deployment orchestration solution?

Answer (score 0):

Terraform operates on a directory level so you can simply define both stacks at the same place as a big group of resources or as modules.

In Terraform, if you need to deploy multiple resources together at the same time then you would typically use a [module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/index.html) and then present a smaller surface area for configuring that module. This also extends to creating modules of modules.

So if you had a module that you created that deployed one service that contained a load balancer, service of some form (such as an ECS task definition; Kubernetes pod, service, deployment etc definition; an AMI) and a database and another module that contained a queue and another service you could then create an over-arching module that contains both of those modules so they are deployed at the same time with a smaller amount of configuration that may be shared between them.

Modules also allow you to define the [source location](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html) as remote such as a git location or from a Terraform registry (both the public one or a private one) which means the Terraform code for the modules don't have to be stored in the same place or checked out/cloned into the same directory.

Comment: Thanks @ydaetskcoR - are you saying that if I define both stacks at the same level then I can deploy both with one command? From what I understand Terraform operates on one stack at a time. Re. modules, the issue here is that using modules per stack it is not really safe to deploy one module at a time. The entire parent stack is apparently supposed to be deployed at once. I am trying to avoid a situation where I need to define my entire infra in one stack definition. I would like to be able to safely deploy indiv. stacks if I wish (in prod-like scenarios) OR all together if I wish (in test).

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the structure of your code but I would suggest splitting out things to the minimal thing you would want to deploy (such as a service and its direct, own dependencies eg databases) is in a single module or a file you can symlink around. Then if you want to deploy 2 services at the same time you just include both the service's modules/files in the same directory and run Terraform against it. Or alternatively keep them completely separate and just run Terraform multiple times against multiple directories.

Comment: If you need something more complicated than that then you need an actual orchestration tool such as Jenkins or some other CI tool or such.